# How can install stock Android 4.0 on my rooted Galaxy S2?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, stock-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I've just rooted my Galaxy S2 to remove all the Samsung applications.

I wanted to install stock android 4 on my device, but i can't seem to find anywhere where the android zip exists.
So please if you can point me where to find the latest release and how to install it.

Note: I have a Mac so I can't install odin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official AOSP* rom for Galaxy S II, but there are many custom roms of ICS available. I'd suggest trying Cyanogenmod 9 nightlies, which are not stable yet, but usually work pretty well. You can find more information from the Cyanogenmod Forums, specifically [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/45674-cm9-instructions-discussion-of-nightlies/).

Note that the nightlies come with no guarantees, use at your own risk.

*AOSP: Android Open Source Project, also known as *stock* or *vanilla*.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a stable alternative for Cyanogenmod ?

Comment: Well, there is AOKP (Android Open Kang Project) which has Milestone releases, which are quite stable (at least on my GTab10.1)... You can find more info at [aokp.co](http://aokp.co) (down right now) or [rootzwiki.com](http://rootzwiki.com/forum/424-aokp/). Or you can try your luck with [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1204) forums.